# Sidebar on hover drags out. (preferably CSS Only)

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, hover

I've been working a website on my spare time, and I can't seem to figure out how to make a navigation like the one FontShop has on their site: https://www.fontshop.com/ It is so, that when you hover on their logo, or in my case, a blank rectangle, a sidebar navigation appears. Preferably I would like to create this with CSS3 only, but if jquery/js suggestions can be made then I will also work with those.

Thanks!

Comment: Is hit a request for someone to give you code for you to use or what? What is it that you've tried, done or what obstacles are you facing? How can we help?

Comment: @AndrewL I don't know what to try. I've been able to create a vertical side navigation, but not make it appear or re-appear. Im trying to create two div's–one to use the hover action, and the other to have the navigation drag out and over the page. But keeping the two connected. Im not asking for a completed code, im looking for a solution in CSS. If it's possible. Im curious as to how I would go about using the :hover state in one div, to change the properties in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the logo (as image or div) and the navigation div in one common container and apply the :hover to the container:

**HTML:**

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>nav1</li>
        <li>nav2</li>
        <li>nav3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg/320px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png" id="logo" alt="stackoverflow" />
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#navigation {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  display: none;
  float: left;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
}

#container:hover #navigation {
  display: block;
}
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/v71fgshe/